# Modifying Linq to remove repetitiveness

Tags: c#, .net, linq

```
private readonly IRepository<Order> _orderRepo; // initialized in the constructor



IRepository<Order> GetOrder(string orderstate)
{
    if(orderstate == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    IQueryable<Order> query = null;

    if(orderstate == "OrderStateChanged")
    {
        query = (from c in _orderRepo.Table
                where c.OrderStateChanged != 0
                select c
            );
    }

    else if (orderstate == "PaymentStateChanged")
    {
        query = (from c in _orderRepo.Table
                where c.PaymentStateChanged != 0
                select c
            );
    }
    /*More else if statement*/
}
```

I used LINQ to extract data from the repo and I have more else if statement. I want to remove the repetitive behavior of my code. 
I have a clue "Expression Tree" but I can't understand How can I use that in my code Or suggest me any other way to remove 
repetitiveness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you **really** want to prevent manually mapping `orderState` to members (using `if/else`, `switch`, `IDictionary`, ...), your only option are indeed expression trees:

```
var orderType = typeof(Order);
var param = Expression.Parameter(orderType);
var member = orderType.GetMember(orderState).FirstOrDefault();
if (member == null) 
{
    /* requested member of "Order" does not exist */
}
var filter = Expression.Lambda<Func<Order, bool>>(  // "param => param.member != 0"
    Expression.NotEqual(                              // "param.member != 0"
        Expression.MakeMemberAccess(param, member),     // "param.member"
        Expression.Constant(0)),                        // "0"
    param);                                           // "param =>"
query = _orderRepo.Table.Where(filter);
```

**Alternative (simpler, but throws `ArgumentException` if the member doesn't exist)**

```
var orderType = typeof(Order);
var param = Expression.Parameter(orderType);
var member = Expression.PropertyOrField(param, orderState); // may throw ArgumentException!
var filter = Expression.Lambda<Func<Order, bool>>(
    Expression.NotEqual(member, Expression.Constant(0)),
    param);
query = _orderRepo.Table.Where(filter);
```

This way you are really generic, even if the object layout of `Order` changes. One disadvantage is of course the risk of invalid `orderState` values leading to non-existing members of `Order` but I'm sure you had some kind of mechanism already, anyway.

**Further reading**

[MSDN - Expression Trees](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb397951(v=vs.90).aspx)

[MSDN - How to: Use Expression Trees to Build Dynamic Queries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb882637.aspx)

[CodeProject - Expression Tree Basics](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/235860/Expression-Tree-Basics)

Comment: Except I would use `Expression.PropertyOrField` rather than `Expression.MakeMemberAccess`.

Comment: thanks @olydis Can you give me an explanation of the expression tree code, or any link where I can master expression tree.

Comment: added comments behind the expression tree code (representing what each part of the expression corresponds to), as well as some links to learn more about the topic

Comment: any feedback about why you unaccepted my answer? did it not work?

Answer (score 1):

You won't get it much better, but the extension method syntax is (IMHO) a bit more concise for this sort of code

```
IEnumerable<Order> GetOrder(string orderstate)
{

    if(orderstate == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    IQueryable<Order> query = _orderRep.Table;

    if(orderstate == "OrderStateChanged")
    {
        query = query.Where(c => c.OrderStateChanged != 0);
    }
    else if (orderstate == "PaymentStateChanged")
    {
        query = query.Where(c => c.PaymentStateChanged != 0);
    }
    /*More else if statement*/
}
```

If you need this filtering in multiple places, you could maintain some kind of dictionary with the expression predicates:

```
static IDictionary<string, Expression<Func<Order,bool>> Predicates = new Dictionary<string, Expression<Func<Order,bool>> 
{
    {"OrderStateChanged", o => o.OrderStateChanged != 0},
    {"OrderPaymentChanged", o => o.PaymentStateChanged != 0},
};
```

Then your method could become something like:

```
IEnumerable<Order> GetOrder(string orderstate)
{
    if (orderstate == null || !Predicates.ContainsKey(orderstate))
        return null; // or throw exception

    var predicate = Predicates[orderstate];

    return _orderRep.Table.Where(predicate);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

LINQ is composable by nature. This means that you can do this:

```
var query = _orderRepoTable.AsQueryable();

switch (orderState)
{
  case "OrderStateChanged": query = query.Where(c => c.OrderStateChanged != 0); break;
  ...
}

// Now query has the filters you want.
```

I'd still stick with the explicit filters, rather than using expression trees to build them based on `orderState` directly - that's just asking for trouble. Using an enum for `orderState` might also be a good idea. Don't worry, this isn't really code repetition - it's just a definition of a language, basically.