# How can pass a column name as a parameter for dynamic search in entity-framework

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, dynamicquery

My requirement is to pass column name along with search data for dynamically searchning from db using linq query in entityframework.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index(string Search, string Column)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Search))
    {
        List<Employee> result = new List<Employee>();
        result = db.Employees.ToList();
        result = result.Where(x => x.Column.ToLower().Contains(Search.ToLower())).ToList();
        return View(result);      
    }
    else
    {
       return View(db.Employees.ToList());  
    }          

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Modifying Linq to remove repetitiveness](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32315061/modifying-linq-to-remove-repetitiveness)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking something like [DLinq](https://dynamiclinq.codeplex.com/documentation). Use the [DLinq nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic.Library/)

```
var result=  db.Employees.Where(Column+".Contains"+ "(\""+ Search.ToLower() + "\")").ToList();
```

The `Column` parameter must match with the name of one string property in your `Employee` entity. I suggest use a try-catch in case you pass a wrong name.

Comment: Thank you so much.Its working fine.I really appreciate for quick & good solution.

Comment: Hi @RajeshVerma, now I saw this is your first question in SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please consider mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.